# How can I config laravel for testing with database?

Tags: laravel, database, automated-tests, phpunit, development-environment

For now I have error with connection when I start php artisan test
• Tests\Feature\ApiTest > index
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:   .  (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I use docker so my connection to db looks like

#### .env

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=mysql
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=laravel_api
    DB_USERNAME=sail
    DB_PASSWORD=password
```

#### database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel_api'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sail'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : []
```

#### phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
                bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
                colors="true"
            >
            <testsuites>
                <testsuite name="Unit">
                    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
                </testsuite>
                <testsuite name="Feature">
                    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
                </testsuite>
            </testsuites>
            <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
                <include>
                    <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
                </include>
            </coverage>
            <php>
                <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
                <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
                <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
                <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
                <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
                <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
                <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
                <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
            </php>
</phpunit>
```

There are three base file that need for config. When I did request to Postman, all works fine. What can I do wrong?

Comment: What is the command you use to run your tests? Do you run the tests in a docker container with docker-compose run?

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed I use php artisan test

Comment: Running `php artisan test` runs the tests locally on your machine. The host you configured `DB_HOST=mysql` is a docker alias and won't work locally. So you'll have to run your tests in the container with `docker-compose run CONTAINER_NAME php artisan test` (or use laravel sail, if thats how you setup the laravel docker stuff)

Comment: I believe the default laravel for CONTAINER_NAME is `laravel.test` so it would be `docker-compose run laravel.test php artisan test`

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed thank for explanation, now I at least understand why there are problems with connection
For now if I use docker-compose run laravel.test php artisan test it send 
error: failed switching to "php": unable to find user php: no matching entries in passwd file

Comment: Be sure to check the docker-compose.yml for the service key you need to use, might not be the same

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed I cheked, in docker-compose.yml
services:
    laravel.test:

etc...